# MongoDB/PHP: search for string with query

Tags: php, arrays, string, mongodb, search

EDIT: I solved it. Just need to use "MongoDB\BSON\Regex".

I'm storing books as documents in MongoDB, with the individual pages stored as strings in an array. I'm trying to implement a search page that can take a string and return all documents that contain it. Can this be done directly with a MongoDB query called using PHP (i.e searching for a substring within the string arrays)?

I'm using MongoDB\Driver ( http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongodb.php ) because it was the only option that worked on my machine, and I couldn't find detailed documentation or tutorials for this particular driver. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Something like

`db.table.find({"bookTextField": /.*(the string).*/})`

EDIT: Of course, replace table by the table name and bookTextField by the field of the table containing the text

Comment: Doesn't work, MongoDB\Driver doesn't have functions like that. The closest thing is functions in MongoDB\Driver\Query, but I have no idea based on the documentation whether it can search for substrings within arrays of strings in a document.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that are blatantly off topic: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions